# function returning two calendaristic dates to represent date of monday and date of sunday according to calendaristic date which is the parameter

Tags: javascript, date-manipulation

Can you help me with a function that receive a parameter which is the calendaristic date(12.4.2020) and returning me two dates that represent dates of monday and sunday(11.30.2020 - 12.06.2020).

What i have until now is:

```
function getWeek(d){
 findDayOfWeek = new Date(d).getDay(); // for exemple if d is 12.04.2020 that line will return 5 that mean friday
}
```

but now i'm blocked. I don't know how to continue that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 functions which return firstDayOfWeek and lastDayOfWeek like

```
function firstDayOfWeek(dateObject, firstDayOfWeekIndex) {

    const dayOfWeek = dateObject.getDay(),
        firstDayOfWeek = new Date(dateObject),
        diff = dayOfWeek >= firstDayOfWeekIndex ?
            dayOfWeek - firstDayOfWeekIndex :
            6 - dayOfWeek

    firstDayOfWeek.setDate(dateObject.getDate() - diff)
    firstDayOfWeek.setHours(0,0,0,0)

    return firstDayOfWeek
}
```

and

```
function lastDayOfWeek(dateObject, lastDayOfWeekIndex) {

    const dayOfWeek = dateObject.getDay(),
        lastDayOfWeek = new Date(dateObject),
        diff = dayOfWeek <= lastDayOfWeekIndex ?
            dayOfWeek - lastDayOfWeekIndex :
            6 - dayOfWeek

    lastDayOfWeek.setDate(dateObject.getDate() - diff)
    lastDayOfWeek.setHours(0,0,0,0)

    return lastDayOfWeek
}
```

now you can call these functions

```
let lastMonday = firstDayOfWeek(new Date(), 1)
let nextSunday = lastDayOfWeek((new Date(), 7)
```